# Do browsers cache video files differently from other file types

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

While attempting to test when a video file is loaded on a webpage, I ran into issues when trying to remove it from Chrome's browser cache.

I couldn't get the file to reappear in the network panel of dev tools when either hard reloading, clearing the browser's cache or by keeping disable cache checked in Chrome's dev tools.

The only way I could get the files to reload was to either start a new private browsing tab or wait a few minutes, when the files would then be reloaded.

Seems to happen on the following page as well as my own:
http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

This also appeared to happen on a number of other browsers as well as Chrome.

So do Chrome and other browsers cache video files differently to other files (possibly to save bandwidth), and is there an easier way to force video files to reload while testing other than starting a new private browsing tab for each page refresh?

Comment: I'm having the same issue; did you ever find a solution to make the file appear in the Network tab?

Comment: Same issue with you